# Failed to dockerize a laravel app (Exit Code 1)

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I am new to Docker. This can be marked as duplicate but none of the other solution works. I am completely clueless. I have been stuck on this for 9 hours. Tried every possible solution to my knowledge from StackOverflow.
I am on Ubuntu 20.04 btw.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.4
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN apt-get install zlib1g-dev -y && apt-get install zlib1g && apt-get install libpng-dev -y && apt-get install -y libzip-dev && apt-get install redis-server -y
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql gd zip
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN composer install
CMD php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8181
EXPOSE 8181
```

**Docker-Compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8009:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file: .env
    working_dir: /app
    command: bash -c 'composer install && php artisan migrate && php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0'
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db
  db:
    image: "mysql:5.7"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rubosa
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=rubosa
      - MYSQL_USER=rubosa
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=rubosa
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8090:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rubosa
```

**.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_ENGINE=InnoDB
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=rubosa_akan_language
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=""
```

**config/database.php**

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'),
```

**Docker Logs**

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = rubosa_akan_language and table_name = dt_migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

**docker ps -a**

```
IMAGE                              STATUS
rubosa_app                         Exited (1) 13 minutes ago
phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin              Up 13 minutes
mysql:5.7                          Up 13 minutes
```

Comment: Db host in your env file should be the name of your docker database which is db

Comment: Thanks. I will try that tomorrow and give you an update.

Comment: Change `DB_HOST=127.0.0.1` to `DB_HOST=db`

Comment: Thank you guys. I now get why DB_HOST=db works. You can post it as an answer.